# How to get HWND of the currently active Windows Explorer window?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-explorer

I know how to get the HWND of the desktop: [GetDesktopWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But I haven't been able to find a function that returns the HWND of the currently **active** [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) main window.

How do I get the HWND of the currently active Windows Explorer window in a safe and reliable manner?

Comment: This is inherently unreliable - even if you get the HWND of the currently-active explorer window (assuming there even is any), there's nothing preventing the window from closing and being destroyed before your program can do anything with the HWND.

Comment: Why?  Whatever you're attempting to do is probably unsupported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the currently active window via [GetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You could then do [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a PID which you can then convert to a process handle with [OpenProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (you will want PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION and PROCESS_VM_READ access rights) and then you can check the process name with [GetModuleFileNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Don't remember to close the process handle afterwards with [CloseHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's some code I just wrote in notepad. You'd probably do something along these lines.

```
DWORD  lpFileName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
DWORD  dwPID;
HANDLE hProcess;
HWND   hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwnd, &dwPID );
hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFOMRATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, dwPID );
GetModuleFileNameEx( hProcess, NULL, lpFileName, _countof( lpFileName ) );
PathStripPath( lpFileName );

if( _tcscmp( _T("explorer.exe"), lpFileName ) == 0 ) {
  _tprintf( _T("explorer window found") );
} else {
  _tprintf( _T("foreground window was not explorer window") );
}
CloseHandle( hProcess );
```

To get all open explorer windows you can use [EnumWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which you provide a callback which receives all the top-level windows. You can then filter out however you want, maybe by process name (above), maybe by class name ([GetClassName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: & @Nick - thank you both for great & educating answers. Since you seem very knowledgeable, perhaps you have an idea about this question, too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270539/how-to-shell-notifyicon-without-adding-an-icon-in-the-notification-area :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're certain that a Windows Explorer window is currently the foreground window you can use [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Otherwise, I think you'd have to enumerate through all windows until you've found the top-most Explorer window. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219933/c-how-to-wait-for-a-pop-up-window-and-select-it-for-input/4221598#4221598) that I wrote up of how to enumerate through all windows*. Then, according to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019066/get-all-window-handles-for-a-process), you can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) to filter windows owned by Explorer.

*It's been a while, but I *think* [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) iterates from the top of the z-order to the bottom.